# How to get R's install.packages to error out in a Dockerfile?

Tags: r

Below is a command that failed, but Docker kept going.  I'm pretty sure this is because the 'warning' ("installation had non-zero exit code") wasn't passed outward as a non-zero exit code to the Rscript invocation.

How can I get this to stop the Docker build?

```
Step 21/44 : RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/prophet_0.1.tar.gz", dependencies=TRUE)'
 ---> Running in 26ba0c1da37c
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/R/lib’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
inferring 'repos = NULL' from 'pkgs'
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/prophet_0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 75619 bytes (73 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 73 KB

ERROR: dependencies ‘extraDistr’, ‘rstan’ are not available for package ‘prophet’
* removing ‘/usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/R/lib/prophet’
Warning message:
In install.packages("https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/prophet_0.1.tar.gz",  :
  installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpAa2XQV/downloaded_packages/prophet_0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Does it work correctly if you first set `options(warn = 2)`? See [`?options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html) (search for `'warn'`) for details.

Comment: @r2evans By god that works! If you submit it as an answer, I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force warnings to be treated as errors (i.e., immediate "stop") by setting  `options(warn = 2)`. From [`?options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html):

```
 'warn': sets the handling of warning messages.  If 'warn' is
      negative all warnings are ignored.  If 'warn' is zero (the
      default) warnings are stored until the top-level function
      returns.  If 10 or fewer warnings were signalled they will be
      printed otherwise a message saying how many were signalled.
      An object called 'last.warning' is created and can be printed
      through the function 'warnings'.  If 'warn' is one, warnings
      are printed as they occur.  If 'warn' is two or larger all
      warnings are turned into errors.
```